# Monitor buttons disabled via DVI

Tags: display, nvidia-geforce

This is my issue: one of my two monitors doesn't react to the buttons. that means no osd, no powering on/off, no changing the brightness.

My setup:

- windows 8 / linux dualboot
- one nvidia geforce 670
- an old apple cinema display
- a more recent iiyama monitor

The monitor being affected seems to depend on the dvi port on the graphics card they are connected to. Switching the port on the card makes the other display ignore its controls (and the first react to its own again, ruling out a hardware defect on either one)

How can I reenable the hardware buttons or change the brightness and turn on/off a specific monitor via software?

Comment: Have you tried swapping which port on the video card each monitor is plugged into?  It may be a video card issue rather than a cable issue.

Comment: sorry for my vocabulary. that is what i meant with "swapping the plugs".

Comment: No worries, I seem to have misread it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Using DVI the monitor accepts digital data from the graphics card and displays them. So the buttons (brightness etc) do not work as they are intended only for analog data via VGA cable. It should switch off and on though... In digital mode, any image adjustment is done using the graphics card's control panel (eg nVidia Control Panel).

Comment: is brightness an image adjustment? and power on/off doesn't work, that's definitivly not an adjustment!